# Ruby on Rails controller design

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I look at examples of Rails controllers, I usually see something like this:

```
class WidgetController < ActionController::Base

  def new
    @widget = Widget.new
  end

  def create
    @widget = Widget.new(params[:id])
    if @widget.save
      redirect_to @widget
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

This works, but there's a couple problems:

### Routes

If I add widgets to my routes.rb file:

```
Example::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :widgets
end
```

`GET /widgets/new` will route to `new` and `POST /widgets` will route to `create`.

If the user enters incorrect information on the new widget page and submits it, their browser will display a URL with `/widgets`, but the new template will be rendered. If the user bookmarks the page and returns later or refreshes the page, the index action will be called instead of the new action, which isn't what the user expects. If there's no index action or if the user doesn't have permission to view it, the response will be a 404.

### Duplication of code

As a contrived example, let's say I had some tricky logic in my new method:

```
def new
  @widget = Widget.new
  do_something_tricky()
end
```

Using the current approach, I'd duplicate that logic in `new` and `create`. I could call `new` from `create`, but then I'd have to modify `new` to check if `@widget` is defined:

```
def new
  @widget ||= Widget.new
  do_something_tricky()
end
```

Plus, this feels wrong because it reduces the orthogonality of the controller actions.

### What to do?

So what's the *Rails way* of resolving this problem? Should I redirect to `new` instead of rendering the new template? Should I call `new` inside of `create`? Should I just live with it? Is there a better way?

Comment: I think would be good Rails made the POST to `/widgets/new` by default, although this implies some redundancy, anyone knows why do they made the POST to `widgets`?

Comment: not exactly an answer, but i'd say that if your users expect to be able to come back later to an incomplete form, you're missing a feature. Your users want a _draft_ feature - so if saving fails, you save your thing _as a draft_ (easy to implement, you just need a boolean column and conditionnals on your validations) which is accessible like any resource (you can even assign them their own controller).

Comment: That's a good point @m_x. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem in "the rails way" and there is no builtin functionality to allow this without getting your hands dirty. What does a user expects when bookmarking a form they just submitted and had errors? Users don't know better, and they shouldn't bookmark a failed form.

I think redirecting to `new_widget_path` is the cleanest solution. Yet, you should keep the errors and display them on the form. For this I recommend you keep the params in session (which I expect to be smaller than a serialized Widget object).

```
def new
  @widget = widget_from_session || Widget.new 
end

def widget_from_session
  Widget.new(session.delete(:widget_params)) if session[:widget_params].present?
end
private :widget_from_session

# Before the redirect
session[:widget_params] =  params
```

The code is self explanatory, `Widget.new` will only be called when `widget_from_session` returns nil, this is when session[:widget_params] is present. Calling `delete` on a hash will return de deleted value and delete it from the original hash.

**UPDATE** Option 2
What about submitting the form using ajax? Your controller could benefit from:

```
  respond_to :html, :json

  ...

  def create
    @widget = Widget.new params[:widget]
    @widget
    respond_with @widget, location: nil
  end
```

Based on the response code (which is set by Rails: 201 Created or 422 Unprocessable Entity), you could show the errors (available in the body of the response when validations fail) or redirect the user to @widget

This is how StackOverflow does it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. They submit the form asynchronously.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think about storing the object in the session. I wonder if there's a way this could be done more generically. That being said, I think it's a dangerous attitude to think the user should expect bookmarking a link to fail, no matter what the circumstances.

Comment: I was playing the arrogant developer card to prove a point. Of course, we have to worry about the users, but I strongly oppose babysitting them. You brought an excellent use case (user attempting to bookmark a failed form) that didn't cross my mind before, and I think it will be a great question/discussion for an UX group.

Comment: Are there any security concerns with storing the user's data in the session? For instance, if we were creating a `User` model with a password field, wouldn't that be stored in plain text?

Comment: You wouldn't want to store the password in session. For example, devise will delete the password and password_confirmation from the params before rendering 'new', otherwise it will be visible in the html. Same reason, credit cards are commonly cleared when the submission failed.

Answer (score 1):

you put `do_something_tricky()` in its own method and call it inside the create action (but only when you're rendering the new template, ie when validation fails).

As for the bookmark issue, I don't know a good way to prevent that but to modify the routes and set the create action to the new action but using `POST`

```
get '/users/new' => 'users#new'
post '/users/new' => 'users#create'
```

UPDATE: using `resources`

```
resources :platos, except: :create do
  post '/new' => 'plates#create', on: :collection, as: :create
end
```

then you can use `create_platos_path` in your forms

Comment: I realize I could write my own routes, but I don't *want* to. It feels wrong to not use resource routes for resources. I was hoping for a baked in solution.

Comment: i don't know of any baked in solution to do what you want. If you want to use `resources` in routes, you can try my updated answer.

Comment: The point of do_something_tricky was to illustrate how the code violates the DRY principle. Say you had to do something before and after the post was created. I'm pointing out an ugly example, not trying to solve a specific problem.

Comment: Plus, it still feels wrong to use the `/new` route to call the `create` method.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think the *Rails way* of solving the problem would be to put the tricky method onto the model or as a helper method, so the controller stays "thin" and you don't have to make sure to add custom behavior to both `#new` and `#create`.

EDIT: For further reading, I'd recommend the "Rails AntiPatterns" book, as they go through a lot of these common design issues and give potential solutions.

Comment: *Rails Antipatterns* looks like a good read. Thanks for pointing it out. Any thoughts on how to avoid the routing problems?

Comment: I'd argue that it's not actually a problem - I wouldn't worry about people being able to bookmark the page to which they POST invalid data. If it were part of a multi-page wizard type of flow, that might be a special use case that might require redirecting to intermediate pages that have state information in the URL. In this case, since it's already redirecting to the `show` action for a successfully created object, they'd be able to bookmark that pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write same function in two action , use before_filter instead.

If you want to have "widget_new_url" after incorrect submission then in your form add url of new widget path something like :url => widget_new_path .

Rails takes the url from Form .

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before, so I use edit action instead.

Here is my code.

Routes:

```
resources :wines do
  collection do
    get :create_wine, as: :create_wine
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
def create_wine
  @wine = Wine.find_uncomplete_or_create_without_validation(current_user)
  redirect_to edit_wine_path(@wine)
end

def edit
  @wine = Wine.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @wine = Wine.find(params[:id])
  if @wine.update_attributes(params[:wine])
    redirect_to @wine, notice: "#{@wine.name} updated"
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Model:

```
def self.find_uncomplete_or_create_without_validation(user)
  wine = user.wines.uncomplete.first || self.create_without_validation(user)
end

def self.create_without_validation(user)
  wine = user.wines.build
  wine.save(validate: false)
  wine
end
```

View:

```
= simple_form_for @wine, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.input :complete, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: 'true' }
```

What I did is create a new action 'create_wine' with get action.

1. If user request 'create_wine', it will create a new wine without validation and redirect to edit action with a update form for attributes and a hidden field for compele .
2. If user has create before but gave up saving the wine it will return the last uncompleted wine.

Which means whether use save it or not, the url will be the same to /wines/:id.

Not really good for RESTful design, but solve my problem. If there is any better solution please let me know.

Comment: This fails with database validations (such as `:null => false`).